# ASP.NET MVC Role based Privileges for Controller Actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ASP.NET MVC4 web application with tables users, roles and rolePrivileges

userid username password roleid] values:
1      user1    12345     3,
2      user2    12345     1,
3      user3    12345     2

[roleid,  rolename ] values:
1       admin,
2       client,
3       guest,
4       ...

[Roleid, Action,    GrantAccess] values:
1      /Home/Index  Y
1      /Home/Settings Y
1      /Home/Dashboard Y
2      /Home/Index  Y
2      /Home/Settings N
2      /Home/Dashboard Y
3      /Home/Index Y
3      /Home/Settings N
3      /Home/Dashboard N

I would like to achieve the following in ASP.NET MVC forms authentication:

A controller action should be dynamically granted denied access to a role , and if a user tries to access a controller action which the user is not granted access the application should signout.

1) I want to know the best way to achieve this since hardcoding the rolename like Authorize(Roles="admin")] will not work

2) I also have user specific settings which would need to be initialized on user log in ,in asp.net forms this was stored in session variables can the same be done using TempData in asp.net MVC is this is best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an action filter based on a role group instead of a role.  The role group could be stored in your database in a 1 to many relationship.  (i.e. 1 group has many roles).  Then feed the group name to the action filter.

```
public class RoleGroupFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string [] users = new string[] {};
        string [] roles = new string[] {};

        // get the roles / users for the group from your db or storage
        // below is an example only
        roles = mydb.RoleGroups.Where(r=>r.Name == GroupName).Select(r=>r.Roles).ToArray();

        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
        var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();

        if (!roles.Any(r => userRoles.Contains(r)) && !users.Contains(user.Identity.Name))
        {
            // return a not found result or redirect to an action
            filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
        }
    }
}
```

To use you can simply create administration pages to manage your role groups.  And adding the filter to your controller or action is very easy.

```
[RoleGroupFilter(GroupName="MyGroup")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

In the example above I also allowed adding users to the role group but that would be your choice.

Comment: Does this mean that groups will be pre-defined in the database?

Comment: So just check if action is listed for the user using   string action = filterContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

Comment: Yes you have to pre-define the groups in the database.

Comment: I'm facing a similar scenario, can you please tell me how "MyGroup" got its values from?

Comment: I've put in an example of how to get it from the database.